# Comparing api request with jdbc values

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I am doing api request automation using jmeter. i want to compare api request values with jdbc values after execution.how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) for your database to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to your Test Plan
3. Add [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request and execute the relevant query to get the value from the DB and store result into a JMeter Variable
4. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) as a child of the request and fetch the value from the API response
5. Compare the values from steps 3 and 4 using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion)

You can see [How to Retrieve Database Data for API Testing with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-retrieve-database-data-for-api-testing-with-jmeter) article for reference configuration.